# Braces in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say for example, you have a .json file with `"father": {"name":"Bob"}` and a javascript file that gets the data from it and stores it in an array called *family*.

`{{family.father.name}}` would then print out the father's name on the html page.

Would it be possible to do something like:

In the javascript file:

```
$scope.member = "father";
```

In index.html:

```
{{family.{{member}}.name}}  
// Is there some way to replace father with a variable
// from the javascript file? Just curious.
```

Comment: you said `and stores it in an array called family`.  Did you mean "an object called family"?  Because if `family` is truly an array, then the dictionary notation won't work. You would have to search through the array until you found the `member` you were looking for...

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say object.

Comment: ok, then yes, @vittore's answer will work.  But you'll need binding braces: `{{family[member].name}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dictionary notation, yes

```
var member = 'father'

family[member].name  === family.father.name
```

Or in angular

js:

```
$scope.member = 'father'
$scope.family = { 'father': { name : 'Bob' } }
```

html:

```
{{ family[member].name }}
```

Will output 'Bob'